# How to View tasks by Assigned to

Tags: view, tasks, grouping, task-assignment

View does not offer to set a group by "Assigned To". I am looking for a view where I can group by people "Assigned To". If a task is assigned to more than one person, that task should appear either under a "person1/person2/..." grouping or repeated task unedr each individua

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Assigned To` field by default support multiple selection.

From List Settings -> Assigned To -> Remove Multi Select Option. Now you can select `Assigned To` in the group by screen.

Comment: What if there is more than one person working on a task? I like them both to be able to see their tasks without having to make another copy with another name assignation